# Full screen mobile menu

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, hamburger-menu

I have created a mobile menu on my clients website:
[mBuy.nl](http://acc-www.mbuy.nl)

I am a designer and I work with WordPress, I have basic knowledge of CSS.

On tablet and mobile size I have a hamburger menu.

[Mobile & tablet what it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIC73.png)

[Mobile & tablet how I would like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq6Wc.jpg)

I would like the mobile menu to be 100% of the viewport height. 
Despite trying different methods, I can't get it to work.

Especially since I am using a WordPress theme I find it difficult to copy and paste any code here.

Thank you!

Comment: add some css to your mobile menu wrapper, like: `height: 100vh`, or `min-height:100vh`

Comment: This is crazy, I've been trying to achieve it all day yesterday. Using those properties, seems I've been trying to add it to the wrong selector. Thank you very much Samvel!

Comment: so, you fixed it?

Comment: Definitely, thank you!

Comment: then, please accept my answer as right: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Add to your menu wrapper this code:

`height: 100vh`, or `min-height:100vh`

`vh` is taking the full height of page screen and make item full height, widht of it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this below code on line no 1853 in

http://acc-www.mbuy.nl/wp-content/themes/h-code/assets/css/responsive.css?ver=1.8.3

```
.static-sticky .text-right {
    top: 0;
}
```